# Why Spring Security InMemoryAuthentication do not authenticate me

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I only have the following three classes in my project and a view file. No config files. I have tried to configure spring security on an spring mvc app.

When i run this as java application and access it in browser it asks for password.

i m entering user and password in the respective form fields but it does not authenticate.

I checked logs and found this line

`Using default security password: 75a836df-d369-4600-aad2-a50567ebd283`

When ii used this it successfully logged me in.

> I cant understand this. Can anyone explain this to me? Am I missing
>   something?

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");


    }
}

package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}

package hello;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    private String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World", required=false) String name, Model model) {


        model.addAttribute("name", name);

        return "greeting";

    }
}
```

> I am asking that why it is not logging me in using the username as
>   "user" and password as "password"

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Do you actually mean that you used "use"? In that case, the problem is that the default username is "user". If that's not what you mean, then what in the world do you mean by "used this" to log in? I would guess that perhaps your problem is that your `configureGlobal` method is `private` instead of `public`.

Comment: Also, for future reference: Put an output statement or debug breakpoint in methods like that that don't seem to be having the expected effect, to see whether they're being called at all.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo I meant i am using user and password as the login details just like they are present in the authentication code.

Comment: I am asking that why it is not logging me in using the username as "user" and password as "password"

Comment: I have made the method public but still it is not logging me in. But the question is why it has logged me in when i put the password taken from logs, the line in the log is what i have shown in my question with the password. @chrylis you can see my above comments too.

Comment: You didn't annotate your class with `@Configuration` or any other stereotype, so Spring's not even going to try instantiating the class. Put debugging logging in that method and make it run!

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue. I have to change

```
@EnableWebSecurity
```

to

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
```

on the `SecurityConfig` class.

Actually i am in the process of learning Spring framework and I have found that with so many options there are lot of different approaches available and discussed all over the internet. So therefore such issues occur.

Comment: Also note that `@EnableWebSecurity` is *very* new.

Comment: This is why you need to explain Spring version and maybe more in depth your configuration. Anyway, great solution

Answer (score 0):

You should override method `configure` in your implementation of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
```

What you did is implemented method configureGlobal, which is not presented in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, and Spring knows nothing about this method.

Comment: Spring Security will automatically send the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` through an `@Autowired void` method that takes it as a parameter.

Comment: ok, It works, but still this approach looks strange. What is the reason to use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in this case?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. There's a lot about the way Spring Security is built that doesn't make sense to me, and the only reason I use it is that it's already integrated with a number of other tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code, in your code config method is missing

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true,prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


     @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
              auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("khan1234").roles("ADMIN");
              auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("vaquar").password("khan1234").roles("USER");

        }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER").and().httpBasic();//.and().headers().disable();
        //.and().formLogin();


    }
}
```